# read : separated fscanf in C

Tags: c

```
struct Combo { 
    float price;    
    char code[5];
    char description[100];
    char name[50];  
    int combo_trans;    

} combo, combo1, combo2, combo3, combo4, combo5, csum;

fscanf(cfp, "%5[^:]:%[^:]:%f:%[^\n]\n", combo1.code, combo1.name, &combo1.price, combo1.description);

    printf("Code  : %s\n",combo1.code);
    printf("Name     : %s\n",combo1.name);
    printf("Price    : RM %.2f\n",combo1.price);
    printf("Description    : %s\n",combo1.description);
```

example input

```
C0001:Lunch Deal Set A:10.99:Burger and drink
```

My output is:

```
Code  : C0003 Nugget and drink
Name     : Teatime Saver
Price    : RM 6.99
Description    :  Nugget and drink
```

But I want the Code to be just C0003, please enlighten me where exactly did I do wrong? Because I've been trying to get it right the past few days. Thank you!

Comment: You might want to learn about the [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), the [`strtok`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) and the [`strtof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) functions, which could help you achieve what you want.

Comment: Please post the `struct` definition in the question, so we can see the `combo1.code` string length available. Which I guess is followed by `combo1.description` and is too short.

Comment: Storing `"C0001"` takes 6 characters, not 5.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It has to be initialized to 6. Thank you for the kind comments everyone.

```
struct Combo { 
    float price;    
    char code[6];
    char description[100];
    char name[50];  
    int combo_trans;    

} combo, combo1, combo2, combo3, combo4, combo5, csum;
```